# How to import Room Persistence Library to an Android project

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I recently saw the new feature announced on Google I/O Room Persistence Library to work with Sqlite databases on Android. I have been looking to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and I don't find which dependencies I should import to my gradle file on my Android project. Someone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's possible to find the dependencies on [the example codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-persistence/blob/master/app/build.gradle) for the new architecture components.

**Root :**

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

**For Room:**

```
  implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
  annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

**For Lifecycle dependencies:**

```
  implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1'
  annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

**Adding Rxjava2 objects as result for our queries:**

```
  implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

**Test migrations:**

```
  testImplementation'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 7):

On your project **root** `build.gradle` you have to add Google's maven repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // For Room Persistence Library
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And then on the `build.gradle` of the **Module** you should add:

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha1'
testCompile'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Add this if you want to use **RxJava2** `Publisher` and `Flowable` objects as a result of your queries

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

And finally add also this dependency to **test migrations**

```
testCompile'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

**Update**: The libraries <strike>are still marked as *Alpha1* so I guess the version number will be updated soon, maybe using `1.0.+` until there is a *final* version could be a good idea</strike> have been updated and [as definded on the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#room) you can use `room 1.1.1` using this dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   def room_version = "1.1.1"

   implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
   annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" // use kapt for Kotlin

   // optional - RxJava support for Room
   implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

   // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
   implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"

   // Test helpers
   testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
}
```

Comment: I have a module in which I use Room. The module is a java library. I add the dependencies but get the following error in sync Project with Gradle files


Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.    So is it a problem to use Room with a Java Library?

Comment: Got the same problem

Comment: Ok, the problem for me was that I placed things in the wrong build.gradle files. see  @live-love's answer for another good solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try this to compile Room Persistence library

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1';
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1';
```

And add this in root level build gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Android doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html):

Add the Google Maven repository
Android Studio projects aren't configured to access this repository by default.

To add it to your project, open the build.gradle file for your project (not the ones for your app or module) and add the highlighted line as shown below:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Add Architecture Components

Open the build.gradle file for your app or module and add the artifacts that you need as dependencies:

For Lifecycles, LiveData, and ViewModel, add:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

For Room, add:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

Answer (score 5):

open **build.gradle(Project: projectName)** and add this lines if it doesn't exist.

This enables access to google repository

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
 }
}
```

next open **build.gradle(Module:app)** and add this two lines to existing dependencies

> For Java

```
def room_version = "1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

> For Kotlin

paste this line outside of the dependencies or android scope at the top where kotlin plugins are applied

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

add this lines to dependencies

```
def room_version = "1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

> to keep yourself updated with the recent dependencies version visit [mvn repository for room](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.persistence.room/runtime)

here you will find the latest version.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

For **androidX** and kapt

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    * Add these in project level gradle

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
    }


    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
        supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
        archRoomVersion = "1.0.0-alpha1"
    }


    * Add these in module level gradle dependencies

dependencies {

     compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion;
        annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with the latest version of Android Studio 3.1.

Under Gradle Scripts folder,
in the **Project** build.gradle, add:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

...

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

In the **Module** build.gradle, add:

```
dependencies {

...
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Answer (score 1):

Current (2018 02 14) versions are

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha1'

compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the `build.gradle` file for **your project** (not the ones for your app or module) and add:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Open the `build.gradle` file for **your app or module** and add the artifacts that you need as dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

}
```

Reference: [Android Adding Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2019 if you wish to use Room with Kotlin, AndroidX, Coroutines or RxJava add lines below.

```
   // Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:' + rootProject.roomVersion
    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:' + rootProject.roomVersion
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:' + rootProject.roomVersion
    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:' + rootProject.roomVersion
```

Comment: Do you know if we need to use both kapt '...room-compiler' alongside annotationProcessor '...room-compiler' if Room is used in Kotlin and JAVA code?

Answer (score 0):

Bouncing off @Thracian's answer, here's what I had to do while following this documentation:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#13

```
    /* Room */
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.1.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
```

Also within `android {}` I had to add:

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Despite what I've read, with Kotlin you still must use `annotationProcessor`

Answer (score 0):

```
def room_version = "2.2.3"
def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"   // ViewModel and LiveData
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```